# How do I list only resources a specific user created in a form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a booking app. There is a User model, Services model, and an Appointments model.

There are many users who can create many services. A service can have many appointments.

I'm using the User#show page for booking with a particular user. In the form there is a select box that lists the Services available. Then you add in your time for the Service you chose.

How do I only show the services for that particular user, the user whose page I am on?

Currently it will list all services created by all users.

USERS CONTROLLER

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  before_action :load_services, only: [:show]

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @appointment = Appointment.new
  end

  private

    def load_services
      @services = Service.all.collect {|service| [ service.title, service.id] }
    end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There are many users who can create many services

Since **user has many services you need to use @user.services( to get services related to that user)** instead of Service.all, try:

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @appointment = Appointment.new
  @services = @user.services.collect {|service| [ service.title, service.id] }
end
```

And in your form

```
<%= f.select(:service_id, @services) %>
```